# Position slide out panel below top nav

Tags: css, flexbox

I am working on a slide-out panel (following this [link](https://codepen.io/jasesmith/pen/raqBpm)), In the tutorial, I can see how I can achieve the slide-out panel from the right side using a fixed display - but I want the panel to appear below the top black nav bar as opposed to having the fixed panel overlap the entire vertical height. Is there a way I can set the 'top' to a value relative to the navbar height?

[image]

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>CssTest</title>
    <style>
        .main{
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
        .top {
            background-color: black;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: flex-start;
        }

        .a {
            background-color: brown;
        }

        .b {
            background-color: coral;           
        }

        .content{
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            background-color: darkgoldenrod;
            justify-content: flex-start;
        }

        .content-panel{
            position: fixed;
            background-color: darkorange;
            top:0;
            bottom:0;
            right:0;
            width: 30em;
            /*
            transform: translateX(0%);
            transition: .3s ease-out;
            */
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="top">
            <div class="a">AAAAAAAA</div>
            <div class="b">BBBBBBBB</div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="content-main">content</div>
            <div class="content-panel">
                this is panel area.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: AFAIK, you can't give relative values to a fixed element, that only applies to position: absolute (having the parent taken as a relative reference). Additionally, the problem with the vertical height doesn't seem to be the top attribute but the combination of top and bottom, when both are set to 0, it forces the fixed element to cover the whole screen. I suggest removing bottom: 0 or changing it to auto, then giving your panel the corresponding height value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only do that, if you have a fixed header, that is always visible. Otherwise it will look weird if the user scrolls down.

If your header nav bar has always the same height, just set a fixed top value.
If not, the only way is to use javascript. This example will set the `top` value of the panel to the bottom of the header on pageload.

```js
window.onload = function () {
  var headerNaV = document.querySelector(".top");
  var contentPanel = document.querySelector(".content-panel");
  
  contentPanel.style.top = headerNaV.offsetHeight + headerNaV.offsetTop + "px";
}
```

```css
.main{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.top {
    background-color: black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

.a {
    background-color: brown;
}

.b {
    background-color: coral;           
}

.content{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: darkgoldenrod;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

.content-panel{
    position: fixed;
    background-color: darkorange;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    width: 30em;
    /*
    transform: translateX(0%);
    transition: .3s ease-out;
    */
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>CssTest</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="top">
            <div class="a">AAAAAAAA</div>
            <div class="b">BBBBBBBB</div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="content-main">content</div>
            <div class="content-panel">
                this is panel area.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```